# setInterval() to loop after some idle timeout and reset when mouse move or touch

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout, setinterval

So what i am trying to achieve is if no one moves the mouse or click or touch (basically if there is no activity on the website) after some time (5 minutes) to start with text animation but text should loop every 15 seconds until someone starts poking around on website again.

And i have this function so far working to some point

```
        $(function(){
          var idleTimer;
          var idleInterval;
          function resetTimer(){
            clearTimeout(idleTimer);
            clearInterval(idleInterval);
            idleTimer = setTimeout(idleloop,30 * 1000);
          }
          $(document.body).bind('mousemove keydown click',resetTimer); //space separated events list that we want to monitor
          resetTimer(); // Start the timer when the page loads
        });

        function idleloop() {
            idleInterval = setInterval(whenUserIdle,15 * 1000);
        }
        function whenUserIdle(){
            if(isOpened) {
                goHome();
            } else {
                if(isBurst) {
                    Partallan.start();
                } else {
                    Partallan.stop();
                }
            }
        };
```

But when using this, loop interval is is not reset, `clearInterval` should stop interval loop but when i start browsing website again after some time of inactivity the setInterval loop just interrupts me and continues to loop every 15 seconds.

I can't figure out how to stop everything when there is activity on the website, and continue when there is no activity.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/q4500voy/

Here I have added event on `document` instead of `document.body`

```
      $(document).bind('mousemove keydown click',resetTimer);
```

It seemed that `document.body` selector worked for only `keydown` event.